# Intuition behind the 4 in the heat equation solution in comparison to the pdf of the Gaussian (normal) distribution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

The heat equation

$$u(t,x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi kt}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{4kt}\right)$$

is presented as a Gaussian distribution changing with time from a point source at time zero at the origin (Dirac). It makes sense that the variance of the Gaussian increases with time, and it is $\sigma^2 = kt:$

$$\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right).$$

Well, almost! Then there is that pesky $4$ turned into a $2$ in the Gaussian.

I understand that as long as it fulfills the heat equation, $u_t=k\nabla^2u,$ we are good. And it does:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(t,x)=k\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(t,x)=k\frac{1}{8\sqrt{\pi k t^5}}\exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{4kt}\right)\left(x^2-2kt \right)$$

> But why is the denominator doubled in the heat equation? There surely is a physical way to just see it...

Comment: It seems $\sigma^2 = 2kt$ instead? It is just a scaling of time, no?

Comment: @mathreadler Why is that not absorbed into the heat conductivity index $k?$ It seems as there ought to be a similar interpretation as the splitting in $1/2$ of the Dirac spike on either side of the zero value in the wave equation...

Comment: $$\frac 1 2 \delta(x-ct) + \frac 1 2 \delta(x+ ct)$$

Comment: I don't see any Dirac spikes. Did you forget to write something down?

Comment: @mathreadler Correct me if I got it wrong, but I thought the equation I transcribed in my question was the evolution of the heat distribution after a spike of heat applied at time zero at the origin.

Comment: Yes that sounds familiar, I just didn't see it anywhere in the question.

Comment: I've never checked...but I thought the physicist's one (the "Heat kernel") should be chosen so that its $k$ that pops out in the equation, and the probabilist's one (the "Gaussian") should be chosen so that the variance is $\sigma^2$, and it just so happens that these needs are different by a factor of 2 when you compare the "standard" versions of the functions

Comment: @CalvinKhor that also sounds reasonable. The probabilistic one is normalized to integrate to one.

Comment: @mathreadler they're both of the form $\frac1{ \lambda\sqrt{\pi}} \exp( - (x/\lambda)^2)$ and these guys have integral 1 for any $\lambda>0$ (dimension seems to be 1)

Answer (score 1):

Note that for a normal random variable satisfying 
$$ dX_t = \sigma dW_t $$

Its PDE is,
$$
\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \frac{\partial^2 f(t,x)}{\partial x^2} = 0
$$

Compared with the PDE for the heat equation,

$$\frac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial t}=k\frac{\partial^2 u(t,x)}{\partial x^2}$$

So, the correspondence is $2k$ vs. $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... Could you please spell out the notation in $dX_t = \sigma dW_t$? I don't know if $X_t$ and $W_t$ are two normal random variables with different mean and standard deviation, and I don't know what the $d$ in front of them is doing. Thank you!

Comment: @Butternut - $W_t$ is just a Brownian motion which generates a normal distribution of variance $t$. $X_t = \sigma W_t$ is proportional to $W_t$, scaled by the variance $\sigma^2$. The 'd' denotes its stochastic differential equation.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, and would like to accept it, but I am having problems finding a reference to build up my understanding of the formulas at the beginning of your post. The closest I got is the Wikipedia page on Wiener process. Do you have any links or keywords to search these equations?

Comment: @Butternut - You're right. I can't seem to find good references directly relevant to the question you posted. Wiener process is such a broad topic and is covered from various aspects. The link attached is more relevant, which establishes the partial differential equation of the Wiener process.

Comment: What is the linked attached?

Comment: @Butternut - Sorry, forgot. It may be still overly notational. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman–Kac_formula

Comment: There has to be some sort of deep connection, and I think you are pointing to it. In [here](https://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/436.A1.12f/PDE_Sources_PDE.pdf) your PDE is arrived at by splitting the probability of getting to a point (unidimensional case) from the left or from the right, and Taylor expanding. I have the intuition that this halving process comes into play in the diffusion of the heat to the left and to the right after applying a point source at zero... I'd like to dig deeper...

Comment: @Butternut - Yeah, the resemblance ought to result from a point source, as does a stochastic diffusion process starting from $X=0$.